Issues Deploying Blazor Server App with Azure Authentication
I have a blazor app that i've built for my company that uses azure authentication. When testing it locally it works like a charm with the localhost certificate. Once i went to deploy to IIS on a web server I cannot get the app to allow sign in.
I have worked with the systems engineers at my company to create a certificate from our domain controller and uploaded this new certificate to Azure AD as well as updated the corresponding thumbprint in the appsettings file. The azure logs show success for the authentication, but I get a generic "We couldn't sign you in" message after attempting to login. It looks like webpage is looping when it's attempting the login (not sure if thats relevant). In IIS i have created a new site and using web deploy, deployed the application to the new site. The bindings are set to use https and the certificate (it was imported to the web server). Included below is my appsettings (obviously with the specifics redacted). Any indication as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.
"AzureAd": {

"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",

"Domain": "MyCompany.com",

"TenantId": "REDACTED",

"ClientId": "REDACTED",

"ClientCertificates": [

{

"SourceType": "StoreWithThumbprint",

"CertificateStorePath": "CurrentUser/My",

"CertificateThumbprint": "REDACTED"

}

],

"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"

},

"MicrosoftGraph": {

"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",

"Scopes": [ "user.read" ]

}


Please share the code which you have tried ?

The CallbackPath in appsettings.json (/signin-oidc) should align with the redirect URI setup in Azure AD.

Please post your sol as an answer.

The issue has been resolved. There were 2 issues that needed to be addressed to resolve this problem. First, when deploying to the IIS web server, the certificate being used was a machine cert not a user cert so in the appsettings.json "CertificateStorePath": "CurrentUser/My" needed to be replaced with "CertificateStorePath": "LocalMachine/My". The second was the account running the IIS application pool for the site needs to be granted access to the certificate used through the management console.
